# How to assign a string and a string in the vue template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, quasar-framework, quasar

How to assign a string and a string in the vue template?

```
<q-table
:title=`Lista de ${this.$route.params.tipo}`
/>
```

> error  Parsing error: Line 1: Unterminated template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use `this` in templates.  Actually, everything in the template gets a `this` automatically.

```
:title=`Lista de ${\$route.params.tipo}`
```

Or in simple form, without template string:

```
:title='$route.params.tipo'
```

Comment: :title=`Lista de ${$route.params.tipo}` Does not work.

Comment: 60:19  error  'v-bind' directives require an attribute value                            vue/valid-v-bind
  60:26  error  Parsing error: unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value           vue/no-parsing-error
  60:27  error  Parsing error: Line 1: Unterminated template

Answer (score 4):

It`s work

```
:title=' ` Lista de ${$route.params.tipo} ` '
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add quotes around the template interpolation.

```
:title="`Lista de ${$route.params.tipo}`"
```